ō(1) notation. family of little o
Is ō(n) the same as o(n) ? I've been wondering about it and I can't find it in the references. Help me understand. Thanks.

Can you share where you found this designation? In my youth, when there were no computers, we sent articles to the printing house, for example, underlining at the top was used to indicate capital letters - $\overline{o}(n)$ was designation for $O(n)$.

Hi! Thanks for noticing my question.

I've been reading this research https://www.ejpam.com/index.php/ejpam/article/view/4323 and it says the p sub nk = ō(1).

In the article you mention in the comments, the $\ell_{n,k}=\bar{o}_n(1)$ notation is explicitly defined in the first sentence of the proof of Theorem 1 (middle of page 519). It means that $\ell_{n,k}$ goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ uniformly over $k$ in a given set.
So it is a variant of the normal $o_n(.)$ notation which provides uniformity in a second parameter.
I'm not aware of this being an established usage more generally.
